# When trying to start Apache - Cant load “Magick.dll” for module Image::Magick?

Tags: apache-http-server, perl, imagemagick

I have ActiveState Perl 5.10 installed on Windows 2008 machine. I installed ImageMagick-6.8.7-9 Q16 (32-bit) installed. Instead of using ppm to install PerlMagick I built it myself using dmake and gcc because the version of PerlMagick in the ppm repositories only goes up to version 6.83 currently whereas I want 6.87.

After Successfully building PerlMagick and seeing the proof that the files were updated in the 'C:/Perl/site' area I then ran the usual test and it worked:

> perl -e "use Image::Magick; print Image::Magick->QuantumDepth"

But when I try start Apache this error appears in Event Viewer:

> Can't load 'C:/Perl/site/lib/auto/Image/Magick/Magick.dll' for module Image::Magick: load_file:The pecified procedure could not be found at C:/Perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 201.\n

I have installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable 32-bit and 64-bit also as recommended on the ImageMagick website.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there even a get around way of getting Apache working as a hack?

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Have you tried to reboot your machine?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this [posting](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=15208):

> The solution to this problem was to reboot Windows (stopping and
>   starting the Apache 2.2 Windows service also didn't make a
>   difference), even though the path wasn't altered. After rebooting, the
>   ImageMagick-specific lines below didn't cause errors, and the script
>   was compiled and executed successfully and consistently.
>
> One more thing: Make sure you manually download all Windows updates,
>   including right up to the current Service Packs. To make sure you've
>   got all the updates downloaded, keep going back into the Windows
>   Updates system until there are none left to download -- in Windows XP
>   the "Express" mode won't get everything, so you'll need to choose
>   "Custom" and turn everything on (although you won't need the Windows
>   Live stuff).

Comment: Unfortunately updating windows as much as possible and rebooting didn't do the trick. It might have worked for Windows XP but not server 2008